# b * b = b as a Structural Property for <S, *>

Tags: abstract-algebra

I'm studying for an upcoming Abstract Algebra exam and one of the practice questions went like this:

Prove that the following is a structural property for a binary structure (S, *): there exists an element b in S such that b * b = b.

My thinking was that because there is a unique identity element for all groups, we can take b = e. Then, e * e = e for b = e.

I don't have the solutions to the practice problem (Fraleigh Abstract Algebra Sec. 3, #16), so I was hoping for any kind of guidance on the problem (I am NOT asking for the answer). Thanks!

Comment: The term "structural property" is not particularly standard.  Does it mean it is preserved by isomorphisms?

Comment: Yes, the structural property P in A = <S, *> also holds true for some other binary structure B = <S', *'> that is isomorphic to A.

Comment: You can’t invoke any facts about groups, because the structure $\langle S,*\rangle$ need not be a group. The *only* things that you know about it are that $*$ is a binary operation on $S$, and that there is some $b\in S$ such that $b\mathop{*}b=b$. You have to show that if $\langle T,\otimes\rangle$ is a binary structure isomorphic to $\langle S,*\rangle$, then there is some $c\in T$ such that $c\otimes c=c$. If you right down exactly what it means for a map $h:S\to T$ to be an isomorphism, the result falls out at once.